# window.location.href not setting query parameters

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set a new url, I've used:

```
window.location.href = <url>;
window.location.assign(<url>);
```

if the url contains a section with query string parameters, Eg. info?value=1
in IE the url will not show these parameters. I tried the above two in Chrome and Chrome does show the query parameters. What's the hack to get it to work in IE?

Comment: Try wrapping the URL in `encodeURIComponent()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @APAD1 If you do that, it will escape the `?` character, so it won't be treated as the parameter delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
location.assign(encodeURIComponent('/step2.php?id=1'));
```

The problem is likely due to the value of your variables. If they contain special or invalid characters, those needs to be passed through `encodeURIComponent` before being assigned `location.assign`

Comment: There's no difference between `location` and `window.location`.

Comment: Check the update... Early Morning Issue, My bad.. :P